# activeTintColor Not changing Icon Color in react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

```
    HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-home' : 'md-home'}

        />
    ),
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#cd077d',

    },
};
```

I'm trying to change the color of my **TabBarIcon** I have tried the ActiveTintColor but this just seems to change the text color and not the icon color, its currently the default Blue when active.

Comment: Try `tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor })`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
  HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-home' : 'md-home'}
            tintColor={{ tintColor }}

        />
    ),
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#cd077d',

    },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

After having this issue myself I find all the answers here not much helpful as the main problem is just naming of the prop. All you need is to pass `color` prop into the Icon. It will take the `activeTintColor` or `inactiveTintColor` depending on if it is active or not.

```
    HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
            focused={focused}
            name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-home' : 'md-home'}
            color={color}
        />
    ),
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
};
```

just as [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/) intend to show so.

Also please bare in mind that there is a difference between `Bottom Tabs Navigator` and `Material Bottom Tabs` as both are provided by react-navigation 5.x.x

The example the author and I are using is Bottom Tabs Navigator.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not set the color of the returned TabBarIcon component? Take a look at tintColor in the official docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html

```
    export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

In react-navigation Version: 5.x

[providing-a-custom-drawercontent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent)

```
    <Drawer.Screen name="settingscreen" component={Settings}
            options={{
                drawerLabel: "Settings",
                drawerIcon: ({ color }) => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="settings" size={24} style={[styles.icon, { color: color }]} />
            }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

> tabBarIcon
> Function that given { focused: boolean, color: string, size: number } returns a > React.Node, to display in the tab bar.

```
<Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{
    title: '',
    headerShown: false,
    headerShadowVisible: false,
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    tabBarLabel:"Profile",
    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (<FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faBell } size={ 20 } style={{color: color}} />)
}} />
```